# Json object is getting flattened out

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

I am using node.js with express  parser. My input json object is in the following format

```
{
    ObjectA:
    {       
        objectB : [
                    actions : [
                        {                           

                            conditions : 
                                paramA: [
                                {
                                    paramB: 45,
                                    paramC: "00:01"
                                }
```

it is complex and very nested. When i receive the object in the req.body i get it in the following format

```
 ObjectA.ObjectB.actions.[conditions][paramA][0][paramB]
```

Till actions, it comes in nice object format but once it reaches conditions, the whole structure breaks down and it puts the entire data structure in one object. 
Is there some limitation to the nested objects using express or node.

I know it is not a code issue because if i reduce the nesting, everything works fine. Reducing the nesting means moving the conditions directly under the ObjectA.

I am using the following to configure the server

```
   app.use(logger('combined',{stream: expressLogFile}));
   var customValidator = new CustomValidator();
  app.use(bodyParser());
  app.use(expressValidator({
        customValidators: customValidator.validations
  }));

  app.use(methodOverride());
```

Express version :
       "express": "4.9.5"

This happens when i get the data from req.body on the server side. The req.body data looks different from i passed from the client http POST request.

OK... the exact structure is as follows

```
{

        content: {
            f: {
                z: 'b2a98061-9b3b-4ff6-8164-164892d369ad',
                actions: {
                    myactions: [
                        {
                            name : 'My message actions1',
                            title : 'This is the title of my message.1',
                            message : 'Have a nice day.1',
                            conditions: {
                                condition1:
                                    [
                                        {
                                            percentage: 45,
                                            timeoutPeriod: "00:01"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                condition2: [
                                    {
                                        start: "12/12/2014",
                                        end: "14/12/2014"
                                    }
                                ],
                                condition3: [{
                                    from: {
                                        time: "10:00",
                                        period: "am"
                                    },
                                    to: {
                                        time: "2:00",
                                        period: "pm"
                                    }
                                }]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I am expected data from req.body in the format of 
        content.f.action.myactions[0].conditions.condition1[0].precentage
but i revceive
           content.f.action.myactions[0]."[conditions][condition1][0][precentage]"

Comment: What does "once it reaches conditions" mean?  Please show the code you're using in express where the issue occurs.

Comment: Please post a complete and valid JSON data. The one you have shown is invalid.

Comment: Ok now that you have shown the actual json data rephrase your question to use this data.

Comment: My guess would be an issue with either the JSON generation at the source or JSON parsing somewhere.   When you look at the data sent over the network, can you verify whether you're getting the right JSON or not?  That would tell you where to look next.  Also, if you want to call attention to edits to a particular person to draw their help, please precede your comment with @username so it will notify them.  It was by pure luck that I noticed you made an edit.

Comment: Unsure if you found a solution to your problem, but I have encountered the same issue. Will investigate if the problem is on the generation side (JQuery's ajax in my case) or the json module in node (I use body-parser v1.8.1). Let me know if you found anything, will do the same.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced the same issue and also suspected the body-parser module on the nodejs server side. In my case, the problem was on the JSON generation side. I used to send my arguments (straight javascript objects) as data without specifying the content type. I changed the initial:

```
registerHandlers($.ajax({
    'url': "/api/" + name,
    'type': 'POST',
    'data': args
}), name, onSuccess, onFailure, onError);
```

by the following:

```
registerHandlers($.ajax({
    'url': "/api/" + name,
    'type': 'POST',
    'data': JSON.stringify(args),
    'contentType': 'application/json'
}), name, onSuccess, onFailure, onError);
```

and then the JSON was retrieved just fine on the other end.

Answer (score 1):

This is controlled by the express urlEncoder.

Wherever you are defining the parsers, change:

```
  `app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));`
```

to

```
  `app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));`
```

You can read more at https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html Scroll down to the urlencoded section.